# Exportar dados de uma array para uma tabela usando VBA

Tags: array, microsoft-excel, vba

Na `Sheet1` eu tenho uma tabela somente com o Header de cada coluna mas valores em branco, eu rodo um VBA que cria uma Array que tem o mesmo numero de colunas da tabela. Existe alguma forma de exportar todos os valores dessa array para a tabela de Excel de uma vez utilizando o codigo VBA?

Eu Utilizo o codigo abaixo para exportar para a `Sheet1`, queria fazer a mesma função mas exportar direto para dentro de uma tabela na `Sheet1`.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

 Dim Filename As String, line As String
 Dim i As Integer
 DB_Bovespa_Option = Application.Run("Funcao", Range("DATA"), 1, 0, "Bovespa")
 PrintArray DB_Bovespa_Option, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[A2]
 End Sub

 Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, Cl As Range)
     Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Vocês podem andar pelos itens do array usando usando o comando FOR do VBA.
Somente precisa sempre lembrar que o array começa na posição 0 e não na posição 1.

```
Sub test()

    Dim vetor(2) As String
    vetor(0) = "teste1"
    vetor(1) = "teste2"
    vetor(2) = "teste3"

    For i = 0 To 2
        MsgBox vetor(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

No exemplo acima criei um array com 3 posições e mandei o Excel apresentar um box de mensagem com o valor do array.

No lugar de usar o código de "imprimir" na tela a posição do array você pode fazer a célula gravar o resultado. Exemplo:

```
Thisworkbook.activesheet.range("A" & i).value = vetor(i)
```

Se não estiver claro poste sua planilha porque com ela posso te dar uma ajuda direcionada.

at.

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser usar uma função que retorna uma matriz, use retorno 'variant', dimensione o vetor internamente e chame na planilha usando "C+S+Enter".

```
Function respvetor() As Variant

    '   Um vetor qualquer.
    Dim x(1 To 5, 1 To 1) As Single

    '   Uma variável qualquer.
    Dim v As Variant

    '   Valores do vetor.
    x(1, 1) = 5
    x(2, 1) = 4
    x(3, 1) = 3
    x(4, 1) = 2
    x(5, 1) = 1

    '   Saída da função na forma de um arranjo de dados na planilha.
    '   Deve ser feito com Ctrl+Shift+Enter, como qualquer matriz.
    respvetor = x

End Function
```

Boa sorte.